# How to use a string inside GetComponent to connect others files in Unity?

Tags: c#, string, file, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a string list of characters e I'm trying to get information from another exclusive `.cs` file to the main `.cs` file.

How to change this

```
  string character_selected;

  if (character_selected == "Jin")
  {
       gameObject.GetComponent<Jin>().getinfo;
  }

  if (character_selected == "Ken")
  {
       gameObject.GetComponent<Ken>().getinfo;
  }
```

To something like this:

```
string character_selected;

gameObject.GetComponent<character_selected>().getinfo;
```

Comment: Are you asking for us to show you how to write it or are you getting an error?

Comment: so Jin and Ken are classes somewhere?

Comment: In general: Use a Dictionary! Do these even have to be MonoBehaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Jin and Ken are classes (which they have to be if the first code works) then you need to use a different overload of GetComponent https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

```
      string typeName = $"something.something.{character_selected}";
      var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
       gameObject.GetComponent(type);
```

the 'something.something' is there because it needs the complete fully qualified class name